# create objects on the fly with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Problem 1:

I came across this issue where in I need to create objects on the fly based on a loop.

Example:

```
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function (index) {
    $scope.cc + index = buildMeProto();
});
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Can I create `$scope.element` based on an index?

Problem 2:

I also notice that in the HTML if you do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="black in blacks">
    <lightbox name="black+$index" />
</div>
```

you can't append an index to an object, in this case 'black' is an object and index is 0, 1,2 etc.

Is there a each way to piggy ride the index to create or invoke elements?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish by adding these properties on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1**

If you want to create a `$scope` property on the fly you need to use the `[]` notation.

```
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function (index) {
    $scope["cc" + index] = buildMeProto();
});
```

**Problem 2**
You could call a function on the scope that would augment the object by adding a property.

```
$scope.addIndex = function(person, index){
    person.id = index;
};
```

**[Example jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/MMqg7/1/)**

Comment: Thank you Mark. the first part works like a charm. I would've never guessed that one. The second one is still confusing to me, since all I have access to is the HTML. I will love to see if I can put together an object with the correct name by using the $index as part of the name. Can it be done in the HTML?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Mark for adding the fiddle.